# WebSocket: get server certificate during handshake

Tags: c, openssl, websocket

I'm using plain-C WebSocket library called *libwebsockets* to make a connection between client and server. When starting server I specify the server's cert and private key to be able to use SSL connection. It works OK.

When making a client's connection to the server I specify an SSL option to be able to create an SSL connection (using self-signed cert). All those things work as expected.

Now, I need somehow to get server's certificate on the client side during the connection establishment (or during handshake). Is there a way to do this? I can't find anything in the  official documentation.

Thanks in advance.